# is this function injective?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, solution-verification

Is this function injective?

$f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N\times N}$ defined as

$f:n\to (n, n+1)$

$f(n_{1})=f(n_{2})\Rightarrow (n_{1},n_{1}+1)=(n_{2},n_{2}+1)\Rightarrow$

$n_{1}=n_{2} \wedge n_{1}+1=n_{2}+1\Rightarrow n_{1}=n_{2}$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly correct. Why are you not sure it is?

Comment: ah I was just thinking if it was possible to map a natural number to a pair of natural numbers. Just wanted to make sure that it is possible. This is actually a part of a bigger problem when I try to show that the set $\mathbb{N\times N}$ is countable (denumerable)

Comment: Just in case you chose $(n,n+1)$ over $(n,n)$ because of some worry about injectivity, it is worth noting that $f:n\mapsto(n,n)$ is also injective.

Comment: In fact any function $n \mapsto (n,\text{whatever})$ must be injective.

Comment: thanks, it is interesting to see that there are many more injective functions that could work here

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

In general $f:\, A\to B$ is injective if $$\forall a_{1},a_{2}\in A:\, f(a_{1})=f(a_{2})\implies a_{1}=a_{2}$$

By definition, you need to show that for all $n_1,n_2\in \mathbb{N}$ $$f(n_{1})=f(n_{2})\implies n_{1}=n_{2}$$

and this exactly what you have shown.